# Not getting records between a certain date on applying LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
  bindToGridCollection = transactionRecsCollection.
               Where(tran =>  tran.GlhDate >= durationFrom && 
                                      tran.GlhDate <= durationTo).ToList();
```

I am getting only 2 records whereas there should be 7 records between the date i have provided

In transactionRecsCollection i get all the records

Comment: What are values of tran.GlhDate, durationFrom and durationTo? Please indicate hours and minutes here.

Comment: Are you sure about the date and time of (from and to) dates being compared?

Comment: too vaughe... There could be dozen of reasons, why it's not working. Can give some concrete data example ?  Some example source collection sample...

Comment: 13/11/2008 00:00:00 and 02/04/2009 00:00:00

Comment: @vini - note that an enddate of "02/04/2009 0:00" will just include midnight on 02/04, but **not** other times! (You don't provide enough data to state that's the problem, though)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The only reason i can think of why you get only two instead of 7 records is that `GlhDate` is a `DateTime` variable with a time-part and you want to include all records of the given day.

Then you can use [`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) which returns the date component without time:

```
bindToGridCollection = transactionRecsCollection
    .Where(tran =>  tran.GlhDate.Date >= durationFrom.Date  
                 && tran.GlhDate.Date <= durationTo.Date)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is DateTime structure you are using here so do not forget the time part of it.
Try the following and see what happens.

```
bindToGridCollection = transactionRecsCollection.Where(tran =>  tran.GlhDate >= durationFrom && tran.GlhDate < durationTo.AddDays(1)).ToList();
```

Comment: If the dates match (minus time) you would indeed get all the records, since you are checking only the `Date` part ! !

Answer (score 0):

In your given example, problem may be one among these:

1. tran.GlhDate and durationFrom may not be in same date format.
2. durationFrom may be of type string rather than Datetime.
3. tran.GlhDate may be of type string rather than Datetime.